# How to mount device that appears in /proc/devices but not /dev?

Tags: mount, devices, block-device, mknod

I'm using a bare bones Linux distribution running on a Phytec i.MX6 ULL SoM on the Phytec demo board for this SoM.  I need to be able to copy a file from an SD card.

I flashed the SoM NAND from an SD card in the demo board SD card slot so I know the SD card hardware is good.  Now I'm booting from the NAND and attempting to read from the SD card after the OS boots.

When I boot up, there is no `mmc*` device in `dev`:

```
$ ls -l /dev | grep mmc
(no result)
```

However the SD card is apparently visible via `/proc/devices`:

```
$ cat /proc/devices
.
.
.
Block devices:
.
.
.
179 mmc
.
.
.
```

Is there a way I can create an entry in `/dev` from the `/proc/devices` data?  Based on Googling I suspect I should use the `mknod` command but I can't work how.

-- Edit --

Darn, I thought I had it figured out for a second.  Based on this https://programmer.group/manual-creation-of-device-nodes-under-dev-in-linux.html I did:

```
mknod /dev/mmcblk0 b 179 0
mknod /dev/mmcblk0p1 b 179 1
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/
```

But I get the error:

```
mount: /mnt: /dev/mmcblk0p1 is not a valid block device.
```

-- Edit2 --

@user414777

If I do:

```
ls /sys/block
```

I get

```
loop0@     loop3@     loop6@     mtdblock1@ mtdblock4@ ram10@     ram13@     ram2@      ram5@      ram8@
loop1@     loop4@     loop7@     mtdblock2@ ram0@      ram11@     ram14@     ram3@      ram6@      ram9@
loop2@     loop5@     mtdblock0@ mtdblock3@ ram1@      ram12@     ram15@     ram4@      ram7@
```

There is no `mmc` in my `/sys/block`

I'm going to read up on `devtmpfs` as I'm not familiar with that.

-- Edit3 --

Here are my `/dev/block` and `/sys/dev/` block contents:

```
$ ls -l /dev/block

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:0 -> ../ram0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:1 -> ../ram1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:10 -> ../ram10
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:11 -> ../ram11
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:12 -> ../ram12
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:13 -> ../ram13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:14 -> ../ram14
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 1:15 -> ../ram15
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:2 -> ../ram2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:3 -> ../ram3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:4 -> ../ram4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:5 -> ../ram5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:6 -> ../ram6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:7 -> ../ram7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:8 -> ../ram8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jan  1 00:16 1:9 -> ../ram9
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  1 00:16 31:0 -> ../mtdblock0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  1 00:16 31:1 -> ../mtdblock1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  1 00:16 31:2 -> ../mtdblock2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  1 00:16 31:3 -> ../mtdblock3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  1 00:16 31:4 -> ../mtdblock4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:0 -> ../loop0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:1 -> ../loop1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:2 -> ../loop2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:3 -> ../loop3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:4 -> ../loop4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:5 -> ../loop5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:6 -> ../loop6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 Jan  1 00:16 7:7 -> ../loop7

$ ls -l /sys/dev/block

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:0 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram0/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:1 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram1/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:10 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram10/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:11 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram11/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:12 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram12/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:13 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram13/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:14 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram14/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:15 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram15/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:2 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram2/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:3 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram3/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:4 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram4/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:5 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram5/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:6 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram6/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:7 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram7/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:8 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram8/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 1:9 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/ram9/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 31:0 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc/1806000.gpmi-nand/mtd/mtd0/mtdblock0/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 31:1 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc/1806000.gpmi-nand/mtd/mtd1/mtdblock1/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 31:2 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc/1806000.gpmi-nand/mtd/mtd2/mtdblock2/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 31:3 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc/1806000.gpmi-nand/mtd/mtd3/mtdblock3/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:17 31:4 -> ../../devices/soc0/soc/1806000.gpmi-nand/mtd/mtd4/mtdblock4/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:0 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop0/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:1 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop1/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:2 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop2/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:3 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop3/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:4 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop4/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:5 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop5/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:6 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop6/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:16 7:7 -> ../../devices/virtual/block/loop7/
```

I don't seem to have a `/sys/dev/block/179:0`

Comment: Look into the `/dev/block` directory. Look into `/sys/block/mmc*/uevent`. Make sure you have mounted devtmpfs on `/dev`.

Comment: I edited my question to include /sys/block output

Comment: Where does `/sys/dev/block/179:0` points to?

Comment: added more to question again

Comment: Then you most probably don't have that device configured at all (bad device tree, missing module, etc). Try with a less bare-bones distro ;-)